# How can I convert the current QUERY in SQL to different data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to have this QUERY in SQL

```
select homework
from karlos
except
select k_id
from yara
where y_ID is not null;
```

**UPDATE**: basically I just want to rewrite the very top query into another query that outputs the same results but using outer joins without subqueries or set operations

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select s.ID
from student
where not exists (select 1
                  from advisor a
                  where a.s_id = s.id and a.i_id is not null
                 );
```

Comment: Whether its "not exists" or whatever to use, but the point is to do it without using subqueries or set-operations, u just used "and" in your query and you used  a subquery. I'm trying to do it without using set-operations or subqueries

Answer (score 0):

You must `left join` the table `student` to a query that returns the `s_id`s of `advisor` where `i_ID is not null` and in the `where` clause return the unmatched rows:

```
select s.ID
from student s left join (
  select s_id from advisor
  where i_ID is not null
) a on a.s_id = s.ID
where a.s_id is null
```

Depending on your data, this would work without the subquery:

```
select s.ID
from student s left join advisor a
on a.s_id = s.ID
where a.s_id is null or (a.s_id is not null and a.i_ID is null)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @SQLnew why do you want to edit the answer and delete the 2nd query that works for you?

Comment: when I told eariler to change it to the original one I meant the very first one.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood from your query, this should work

```
SELECT ID FROM student s JOIN advisor a ON s.ID IS NOT IN(a.s_id) WHERE a.i_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Yeah you're 100% correct, I'm just trying to modify your query and see if it works on my case, you're getting my idea

Comment: There is something wrong with your Query, but your idea is exactly what I want.